# Manipulate pandas dataframe to display desired output

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame structure:

```
profile_id  user   birthday
123, 124    test1  day1
131, 132    test2  day2
```

What I need to display is:

```
profile_id  user   birthday
123        test1   day1 
124        test1   day1
131        test2   day2
132        test2   day2
```

In the profile_id column I have a couple of ids separated with a comma, and I need to loop through each id.

Comment: https://community.esri.com/thread/210489-python-write-new-row-based-on-comma-separated-values-in-table-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One-liner

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.profile_id.str.count(', ') + 1)].assign(
    profile_id=', '.join(df.profile_id).split(', '))

  profile_id   user birthday
0        123  test1     day1
0        124  test1     day1
1        131  test2     day2
1        132  test2     day2
```

---

#### Broken down

```
sep = ', '
idx = df.index.repeat(df.profile_id.str.count(sep) + 1)
new = sep.join(df.profile_id).split(sep)
df.loc[idx].assign(profile_id=new)

  profile_id   user birthday
0        123  test1     day1
0        124  test1     day1
1        131  test2     day2
1        132  test2     day2
```

---

#### Numpy slice instead of `loc`

also get a fresh index

```
sep = ', '
col = 'profile_id'
p = df[col]
i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(p.str.count(sep) + 1)
pd.DataFrame({
    col: sep.join(p).split(sep),
    **{c: df[c].values[i] for c in df if c != col}
}, columns=df.columns)

  profile_id   user birthday
0        123  test1     day1
1        124  test1     day1
2        131  test2     day2
3        132  test2     day2
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Please consider upvoting some of the other answers as well.  Even if you don't accept the answers as the chosen answer, it is useful to show which you found useful by upvoting.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do

```
In [1127]: dfs = (df.profile_id.str.split(', ', expand=True).stack()
                   .reset_index(name='profile_id'))

In [1128]: df.loc[dfs.level_0].assign(profile_id=dfs.profile_id)
Out[1128]:
  profile_id   user birthday
0        123  test1     day1
0        123  test1     day1
1        124  test2     day2
1        124  test2     day2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with a combination of `concat()` and `.melt()`:

```
>>> pd.concat((
...            df['profile_id'].str.split(', ', expand=True),
...            df.drop('profile_id', axis=1)), axis=1)\
...     .melt(id_vars=['user', 'birthday'], value_name='profile_id')\
...     .drop('variable', axis=1)
    user birthday profile_id
0  test1     day1        123
1  test2     day2        131
2  test1     day1        124
3  test2     day2        132
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.profile_id.str.split(",",expand=True).set_index(a.user).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().rename(columns={0:"profile_id"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `extractall` and `join`:

```
df.join(
    df.pop('profile_id').str.extractall(r'(\d+)').reset_index(1, drop=True)
).rename(columns={0: 'profile_id'})
```

```
    user birthday profile_id
0  test1     day1        123
0  test1     day1        124
1  test2     day2        131
1  test2     day2        132
```